# addClass and removeClass is not working correctly

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

**Sorry** if this is an extremely simple question, but for some reason, I cant get this working.

What I'm trying to do is to add the activeButton class to each list item you click **and** remove the activeButton class to the list-item that **had** the activeButton class before the list-item was clicked.

**Here is a code snippet of my problem**

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.buttons').click(function () {
     $('.activeButton').removeClass('.activeButton');
     $(this).addClass('.activeButton');
   });
  });
```

```css
.buttons {
  /*This is for decorative and visual purposes. 
    So you can ignore the CSS for now.*/
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 10px;
  }

.activeButton {
  border-bottom: 1px solid black;/*I use border-bottom to provide underlines for my text. This allows the underline to be transitioned or animated*/
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
    <li class="buttons activeButton">Link1</li>
    <li class="buttons">Link2</li>
    <li class="buttons">Link3</li>
    <li class="buttons">Link4</li>
   </ul>
```

For the sake of clarification, I will explain my goal and the current problem.

**GOAL:** Once a list item is clicked, the class .activeButton will be added to the list item that was **clicked** and the JS will remove .activeButton from the list item that **originally** had the activeButton class.

**PROBLEM:** The attempted solution that I have coded does not work.

Comment: try using `.toggleClass()`

Comment: "does not work" is not a problem description. Please explain what your code does instead of the expected result.

Comment: you dont need to put the `dot` in addClass and removeClass

Comment: ^and that would make it *"a simple typographical error..."*.

Comment: You do of course realize there is no `.postalProvider` element in the posted code

Comment: Sorry, I was in the middle of editing and my internet went out. So a few of the classes are misplaced. I'm editing to fix the problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like this you mean?

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
  $('.buttons').click(function () {
    $('.buttons').removeClass('activeButton'); // <-- remove from all .buttons class
    $(this).addClass('activeButton'); // <-- add to clicked link only
  });
});
```

```css
.buttons {
  /*This is for decorative and visual purposes. 
    So you can ignore the CSS for now.*/
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 10px;
  }

.activeButton {
  border-bottom: 1px solid black;/*I use border-bottom to provide underlines for my text. This allows the underline to be transitioned or animated*/
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
    <li class="buttons activeButton">Link1</li>
    <li class="buttons">Link2</li>
    <li class="buttons">Link3</li>
    <li class="buttons">Link4</li>
   </ul>
```

Comment: Thank you, this seems to be the most efficient solution.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need the class selector in the strings you pass to `addClass()` and `removeClass()`.

Update as follows:

```
$(function () {
    $('.postalProvider').click(function () {
        $('.activeButton').removeClass('activeButton');
        $(this).addClass('activeButton');
    });
});
```

Comment: Thank you for your correction @BenM. I will edit my code snippet accordingly. But your solution does not seem to work in my IDE. But let me test it in the code snippet and see if it works in there.

Comment: @HTMLNoob What is `.postalProvider`? I don't see that element in the markup you posted in the question.

Answer (score 1):

Update :

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var $buttons = $('.buttons');

    $buttons.click(function () {
        $buttons.removeClass('.activeButton');
        $(this).addClass('.activeButton');
    });
});
```

I think this is what you were after.